# How to encrypt a CMS EnvelopedData value with AES-GCM using BouncyCastle?

Tags: bouncycastle

I can generate a valid CMS EnvelopedData value with AES-CBC using the Kotlin code below:

```kotlin
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSAlgorithm
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator

fun encrypt(plaintext: ByteArray, recipientCertificate: X509CertificateHolder): ByteArray {
    val cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator = CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator()

    val x509Certificate = JcaX509CertificateConverter()
        .getCertificate(recipientCertificate)
    val transKeyGen =
        JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(x509Certificate)
    cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.addRecipientInfoGenerator(transKeyGen)

    val msg = CMSProcessableByteArray(plaintext)
    val encryptor = JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC).build()
    val bcEnvelopedData = cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.generate(msg, encryptor)
    return bcEnvelopedData.encoded
}
```

But if I replace `CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC` with `CMSAlgorithm.AES128_GCM`, `JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder.build()` throws the following error:

```
cannot create key generator: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.6 KeyGenerator not available
```

That error seems to suggest AES-GCM-128 isn't supported, but the fact the object `CMSAlgorithm.AES128_GCM` exists suggests to me that can't be it -- I must be doing something wrong. Maybe the IV isn't generated behind the scenes for me and I have to set it explicitly somehow?

I'm using `org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.64`.

UPDATE: I've found [a test](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/98826f00a322148d9e9bd550c365201d8e68a4df/pkix/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/cms/test/NewEnvelopedDataTest.java#L1478) in the BouncyCastle test suite that uses AES-GCM in EnvelopedData values, and they're also passing `CMSAlgorithm.AES128_GCM` to `JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder` in the same way. The only difference is that they're calling `.setProvider("BC")` before `.build()`, but I've just tried that and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question:

`JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder.setProvider()` must be certainly called before `.build()`, but if the provider isn't registered, you have to pass an instance of `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`.